# Extjs : Unable to create Checkbox

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am getting

```
TypeError {stack: (...), message: "undefined is not a function"}
```

How can I resolve this?

```
if (type == 'CheckBox') {

  var defVal = '';  
    if(config.defaultValue && config.defaultValue !== 'none'){
      defVal =config.defaultValue;
    }
  comp = new Ext.form.CheckBox({  
    id : 'checkBox',
    checked :  true ,
    boxLabel : config.displayKey,
    value  : defVal === true ? true : false,
    disabled : config.isEditable === true ? false : true,
    width : width,
    labelStyle : lblStyle
  });
}
```

Comment: Extjs 3? You'll need `Ext.form.Checkbox` (not `Ext.form.CheckBox`).

Comment: Which ExtJS version do you use?

Comment: `defVal === true ? true : false` *Gnashing of teeth*

Comment: @CD and what is the difference?

Comment: @CD thsnks.. that worked! "Ext.form.Checkbox"  is the correct usage. by mistake I used capital 'B' in checkbox.

Comment: @NikolayLopin I am using ExtJs 3.0

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs you don't instantiate a class like `new ExtJs.form.Checkbox()`. `ExtJs.form.Checkbox()` indeed is not a function.

Edit : it seems that your usage was correct in ExtJs 3.0. My answer may be wrong if you use that old version. But most importantly, you omitted to tell us which function is undefined. You cut out the most important part of the error message.

You need to change your code like this:

```
comp = Ext.create('Ext.form.CheckBox', {
    id : 'checkBox',
    checked : true ,
    boxLabel : config.displayKey,
    value : defVal,
    disabled : !config.isEditable,
    width : width,
    labelStyle : lblStyle
});
```

I simplified a the same time your `value  === true ? false : true`, that can be written as a simple negation `!value`.

You could further simplify and replace `value : defVal === true ? true : false,` by `value : config.defaultValue === true` and remove the first lines dealing with `defVal`.

Comment: I never used it, so I cannot give better advice.